# Select Count from Multiple Tables, Group and Calcualte Percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, count

Currently I have a query that subtracts a count of people who are marked as opt-ins through the `mv_donation_report` table, by the amount of thank-you's delivered within the `mv_fundraiser_report` table as seen here:

```
SELECT cast(A.NUM as float)/cast(A.DENOM as float) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM
(SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "public"."mv_donation_report"
WHERE "public"."mv_donation_report"."opt_in" = TRUE
[[AND "public"."mv_donation_report"."page_name" = {{NonProfit}}]]
[[AND {{DateRangeDM}}]]) AS NUM,

(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "public"."mv_fundraiser_report" 
WHERE "public"."mv_fundraiser_report"."thank_you_delivered" = TRUE
[[AND "public"."mv_fundraiser_report"."ngo_name" = {{NonProfit}}]]
[[AND {{DateRange}}]]) AS DENOM) A
```

Right now I am returning one percentage, but I would like to remove the `WHERE ngo_name` parameter, and return multiple percentages grouped by `ngo_name`/`page_name` (they both have the same meaning and function).

This is what the data output would look like:

```
ngo_name|percentage
ngo1.   |10
ngo2.   |21
ngo3.   |35
ngo4.   |7
```

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to  `join` two queries that aggregate by name, like so?

```
select dr.name, 1.0 * dr.cnt / fr.cnt as percentage
from ( 
    select page_name as name, count(*) as cnt
    FROM public.mv_donation_report
    where opt_in and {{DateRangeDM}}
    group by page_name
) dr
inner join (
    select ngo_name as name, count(*) as cnt
    FROMpublic.mv_fundraiser_report 
    where thank_you_delivered and {{DateRangeDM}}
    group by ngo_name
) fr on fr.name = dr.name
```

Comment: Yes! This looks like exactly what I need, thank you! Only issue is that I'm getting `ERROR: column "mv_donation_report.page_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Any thoughts on why this may be the case?

Comment: @HunterCasillas: sorry, I forgot the `group by` clause in both subqueries. Fixed.

Comment: Ahh that makes total sense, thanks! One last thing: I'm now getting this error: `ERROR: column "dr.cnt" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` How can I work around this and not have to group by count?

Comment: @HunterCasillas: fixed.